Native crash support, signed app bundle doesn't contain native symbols
This is regarding the native crash support  in android.
When generating a Signed App Bundle there is no folder debugsymbols inside in BUNDLE-METADATA folder inside the .aab file
I have followed the instructions from the official docs native chrash support, and have also added the ndk version to my build.gradle
android {
    compileSdk  34
    ndkVersion '26.3.11579264'

under build types i have
buildTypes {
        release {
            ....
          ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'
            }
       }


I have NDK and CMAKE installed and i have also tried to build it with multiple NKD versions: 26.3.11579264, 25.1.8937393(the default) and the latest 27.0.11718014.
Android Gradle Plugin Version is 8.1.1
Gradle Version is 8.0 and i have tried with two CMAKE versions 3.22.1 and 3.18.1

If App Bundle is not generating the Native Debug Symbols ZIP file, you can do it on your own.
Right after the build, Please visit
app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/$VARIANT/out/lib
Note: $VARIANT will be your app variant name value
then copy all the folder from it & create a zip file out of it named native-debug-symbols.zip
DONE, You should be good now..
HAPPY CODING :-)
